# Why isn't my default option selected when loading page using iphone?

Tags: javascript

My javascript doesn't work on iphone for some reason.  I expect it to have the selected value set as the default when the page loads.  This works on Chrome on Android (tested on Galaxy S7).

Can anyone suggest a solution or point out why this doesn't work on iphone?

```
var mobselectmenu = 'A-Z';
    mobselectmenu = document.getElementById("sortBy");

window.onload=function(){
        var mobdefaultSort = '<?php $sort = $request->getParameter('sortvalue'); if(!$sort){ echo 'relevance'; } else { echo $sort; } ?>';
    for(var i=0; i< mobselectmenu.options.length; i++){
        if (mobselectmenu.options[i].value == mobdefaultSort) {
            mobselectmenu.options[i].defaultSelected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not the problem, but `var mobselectmenu = 'A-Z'; mobselectmenu = document.getElementById("sortBy");` makes no sense. That's just `var mobselectmenu = document.getElementById("sortBy");`.

Comment: Rather than changing the value from the `load` event (which is **very** late in the page load process, the user could easily see the unselected value for a second or two), why not output the option with the `selected` attribute? (Since you're apparently generating this code from PHP.)

Comment: Try this: [Javascript window.onload not working in iOS captive portal/network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42568320/javascript-window-onload-not-working-in-ios-captive-portal-network)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I may have to come back to this a bit later on for using the `selected` attribute for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the line within the `if` statement fixed this for iphone:

```
mobselectmenu.options[i].selected = true;
```